# Страница сайта без проверки подлинности ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

Для сайта ASP.NET, работающего в IIS используется проверка подлинности Windows, с чем проблем нет. Но есть необходимость предоставлять одну страницу без проверки подлинности, например http://site/Current/Index.html, собственно в Current имеется только одно представление Index.
Пробовал дополнять web.config следующими строками:

```
<location path="Current">
<system.web>
    <authorization> 
        <allow users ="*"/>
    </authorization>
</system.web>
```

Вышеприведённое добавлял сразу после строк

```
<system.web>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1" />
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1" />
<authentication mode="Windows" />
<authorization>
  <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
```

Но не работает, всё также запрашивает авторизацию.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[AllowAnonymous]` - аттрибут пишется перед контроллером или непосредсвенно экшеном. Позволяет заходить в контроллер без проверки авторизации. [Подробнее](https://andrey.moveax.ru/post/mvc4-allowanonymous-attribute)